# Calls made when class is loaded

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class SuperClass{
    public SuperClass(){
        System.out.println("Super class");
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    int i;
    {
        i=10;
    }
    public SubClass(){
        System.out.println("Subclass");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SubClass sc = new SubClass();
    }
}
```

I did a debug on all possible places and I see that first when the instance is created, it first goes to SuperClass constructor and prints Super Class and only then it comes to the instance variable and then the initialization block and then lastly SubClass constructor and prints SubClass.

But, I had read somewhere that inside the subclass constructor is where super() is called by default and that is when it goes to the superclass constructor!!!

Comment: Default:`public SubClass(){super();System.our.println("Subclass");}`

Comment: You should read the [**Java Language Specification, Section 12.5 Creation of New Class Instances**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5), all details are explained there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SubClass()` constructor implicitly looks like this :

```
 public SubClass(){
    super();
    {
      i=10;
    }
    System.our.println("Subclass");
 }
```

As per the [JLS section 12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) :

> Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new object using the following procedure:
>
> 1. Assign the arguments for the constructor to newly created parameter variables for this constructor invocation.
> 2. If this constructor begins with an explicit constructor invocation (§8.8.7.1) of another constructor in the same class (using this), then evaluate the arguments and process that constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason; otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 3. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using this). If this constructor is for a class other than Object, then this constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a superclass constructor (using super). Evaluate the arguments and process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise, continue with step 4.
> 4. Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class, assigning the values of instance variable initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code for the class. If execution of any of these initializers results in an exception, then no further initializers are processed and this procedure completes abruptly with that same exception. Otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 5. Execute the rest of the body of this constructor. If that execution completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise, this procedure completes normally.

Answer (score 5):

Well, that's because your `SubClass` constructor actually looks like this:

```
public SubClass() {
    super();
    {
       i=10;
    }
    System.out.println("Subclass");
}
```

If you don't call the `super()`; explicitly, compiler will do it for you **implicitly**. That means that the `SuperClass` constructor is called **first** and THEN the `System.out.println("Subclass");

Also, the `super()` must be the first statement in the constructor.

You can check all of this by making the constructor of the `SuperClass` **private** (and in separate file, too). The compiler will show you an error in the `SubClass` constructor saying that there is no default constructor in the `SuperClass`.

Comment: Ok! I think I got it. So, after all the super class constructors are invoked, the initialization blocks are executed and then it comes back to the rest of the execution

Answer (score 1):

A constructor always calls `super()`. That is implicit.

Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

> If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor,
>   the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument
>   constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not have a
>   no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object
>   does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass,
>   there is no problem.